# WebForm's Gridview in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making the transition from webforms to MVC4 framework.  What is a good alternative to a gridview?  Preferably something I could stick a datatable into easily, has sorting, and paging.

Comment: why would you need an alternative to gridview?? asp.net mvc4 supports gridview, the implementation just differs a bit

Comment: @Vogel612 Didn't realize I could use gridview.  I went down the rabbit hole with webGrid's and was becoming rather frustrated.  I'll look into that.

Comment: @walther Trying to expand my knowledge base.  Is what I'm doing go against the MVC pattern?

Comment: concerning walter.. he's got a point.. in general you can usually map the aspx page (almost) 1 : 1 when moving from .net to .net-mvc. the big changes occur in controller and model

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

There is an actively developed [ASP.NET MVC Helper for jQuery DataTables](https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables).